# Select from Column A based on Column B

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables joined together and this is the result of that query,

```
Name   Year
Erin   2015
Erin   NULL
Erin   NULL
Sarah  2010
Peter  2011
```

The two columns are from two different tables. They both have an ID I can match. How do I narrow it down to this result,

```
Name   Year
Erin   2015
Erin   NULL
Erin   NULL
```

When Year = 2015, I want all of Erin's.

SELECT Name

CASE WHEN Year = 2015 THEN

......

END

Rest of the columns I've selected

FROM Table
Joined with 4 other tables

WHERE
Stuff

What can I put in between the CASE statement.

Comment: `WHERE "Stuff" and name = 'Erin'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to see all the records from any name that has at least one record with a `year = '2015'`. If so, then:

```
SELECT Name, Year, Other_Columns
FROM Name N
JOIN YEAR Y on Y.ID = N.ID
WHERE N.ID IN (
     SELECT ID
     FROM YEAR
     WHERE YEAR = '2015'
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You answered my other question as well, which was pretty much similar. It made me realize which table I needed FROM and how I should join my other tables.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Put the same case when into the where clause:

select 
case when .. then 'a' else 'b' end
from TABLE
where
(case when .. then 'a' else 'b' end) = 'b'
;